# Как вызвать родительский метод?

Tags: javascript

```
function Child() {
    this.year = function (n) {
        return n
    }
}

function Parent() {
    this.name = 'olena';
    this.year = function (n) {
        return 5 + n
    }
}
Parent.prototype = new Child();
Parent.prototype
    .constructor = Parent;
parent = new Parent();
alert(parent.name); //olena
alert(parent.year(5)) //10
```

Как добавить возможность вызывать еще и методы родителя, которые могут переопределиться? 
Xочу иметь возможность  вызвать `this.year=function(n){return n}` в созданном объекте.

Comment: Все просто - родителю нужна ссылка на ребенка, ребенку на родителя.

Comment: А ссылку можно передать непосредственно в саму функцию через параметр.

Comment: Я могу сделать так?
function Parent(){
//создать какой нибуть публичный метод
 this.ner=function(n){return new Child().year(n)}

Comment: у меня одного когнитивный диссонанс от этого:

    Parent.prototype = new Child();

Comment: Не у Вас одного когнитивный диссонанс. Я тоже не понимаю, зачем Parent`у менять prototype, если мы от Parent`a наследоваться собираемся? Пишем Child.prototype = Parent и таким образом имеем из Child`a доступ вверх, разве нет?

Answer (score 1):

Вы, кажется, путаете потомка и родителя.
Наследование для того и нужно, чтобы наследники имели методы и свойства родителя. Поэтому, пишите так:

Child.prototype = Parent; // Имеем доступ из наследника вверх, к Родителю.

теперь вызов неизвестной функции у Child будет идти к prototype и проверять её наличие там. Если какая-то функция полиморфна - определена в родителе и в наследнике, то выполняться по умолчанию она будет у наследника. Добираться до родителя, как советовали в комментариях, следует храня ссыллку на родителя.